# Navigate to a specific top tab page in Xamarin Shell

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

My [Xamarin Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/) application defines the following `FlyoutItem` element inside the `AppShell.xaml` file:

```
<FlyoutItem ...>
    <ShellContent Title="A" Route="R1" ... />
    <ShellSection Title="B" Route="R2">
        <ShellContent Title="C" Route="R3" ... />
        <ShellContent Title="D" Route="R4" ... />
    </ShellSection>
    <ShellContent Title="D" Route="R5" .../>
    <ShellContent Title="E" Route="R6" ... />
</FlyoutItem>
```

The behavior I want to obtain is the following:

- Clicking on the `B` page, I want the user to be redirected to the `C` tab of the `ShellSection` named `B` (this is the default behavior and works out-of-the-box).
- Clicking on the `D` page, I want the user to be redirected to the `D` tab of the `ShellSection` named `B`.

How do I obtain this?

Comment: I think the first condition is already working as expected right?

Comment: @Cfun yes, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are ok with the following:

If in case the current selected/displayed page is upper tab "D" (Child of bottom tab "B"), and the user click again in bottom tab "B" nothing will happen, navigation will not go to "C", if in case page "A" or "E" is displayed (other than ones belonging to "B" section) and you click on "B" it will displays "C", the same if you click "D" it will displays "D", than this question may help you.

In your Appshell.cs:

```
public AppShell()
{
...
      InitializeComponent();
      Navigating += Shell_Navigating;
}

private async void Shell_Navigating(object sender, ShellNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Target.Location.OriginalString.Equals("//R5") && e.CanCancel)
    {
        e.Cancel();
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//R2/R4");
    }
}
```